# Python: accessing a global dictionary from another module

Tags: python, global

I wanted to create a module with globals shared across several other modules.
I'm modifying some existing code and I want to minimize the code changes.
So want to do something like:
from globals.py import my_dict # and use that existing name where I've imported.
This works for simple variables, but when I do this for a dictionary this doesn't work, the dictionary is empty.
I can wrap the dictionary in an access method and that works.  Here is some example code.

#access_glbals.py

```
import dc_globals
from dc_globals import show_globals, set_args, get_args
from dc_globals import _args_dict
from dc_globals import _G

set_args({'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3})
show_globals()
print(get_args())
print(_args_dict)
print(dc_globals._args_dict)
print(_G, dc_globals._G)
myargs = dc_globals._args_dict
print(myargs)
```

#dc_globls

```
_args_dict = {}

_G = 'g'

def show_globals():
    print('GAD:', _args_dict.keys())

def set_globals(args_dict):
    global _args_dict
    _args_dict = args_dict

def get_args():
    return _args_dict

def set_args(args):
    global _args_dict
    _args_dict = args
```

When I run accept_globals.py, I get
./ac_globals.py

```
GAD: dict_keys(['a', 'b', 'c'])  -- print of keys from show_globals
>> {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>> **{}                               -- print of _args_dict as imported**
>> {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}         -- print of dc_globals._args_dict
>> g g                              -- print of _G and dc_globals._G
>> {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}         -- print of myargs assigned from dc_glboals._args_dict.
```

Obviously, I started out naively trying to import _args_dict by name and then added the interfaces to understand what was going on.
I clearly have a workaround, but I'm interested in understanding to why one works and the other doesn't.
thanks

Comment: Are you aware that a module namespace is already a "global" dict?  Why wrapping another layer of complexity around that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is this:

```
# access_globals.py
from dc_globals import _args_dict
...
set_args({'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3})
```

```
# dc_globals.py
def set_args(args):
    global _args_dict
    _args_dict = args
```

The `_args_dict` you import at the very beginning, gets *replaced* by `args` when `set_args()` is called. So, the `_args_dict` you previously imported doesn't change, but `dc_globals._args_dict` no longer refers to the that object.

There are two simple solutions to this. First, don't import `_args_dict`, and always access it as an attribute. I prefer this solution in general, because it makes it more clear for future-me that the variable in my code is coming from one of the imports:

```
import dc_globals
...
print(dc_globals._args_dict)
```

The second solution would be to use `dict.update()` instead of assignment, so that you're *changing* but does not *reassigning* `_args_dict`:

```
def set_args(args):
    _args_dict.clear()
    _args_dict.update(args)
```